# How to create a flexible rectangular box with perpendicular height and width line at the center to measure eight and width in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I am wondering if there is a tool to create a flexible box with (+ line )height and width line to measure the object height and width in an image in matlab.I am right now using imline but have to draw the 2 lines perpendicular which sometime goes wrong, hence wondring if there is a tool which I can use.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you have the IP toolbox, a convenient function for this is [`imrect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html)

Here is a working example:

```
im=imread('http://i.imgur.com/Y4106D4.png');
imshow(im);
h = imrect;
pause
pos = getPosition(h);
```

Comment: Hi Jigg, thank you, but I need a flexible rectangle which got " + " in it and I can rotate the rectangle along the vertical axis with that cross " + " in it. Is it possible to do something like that in matlab